# É possível limitar a quantidade de linhas de um atributo de classe que é uma lista via JPQL?

Tags: java, sql, java-ee, java-ee-7, jpql

Eu tenho a query abaixo em JPQL

```
FROM User u INNER JOIN FETCH u.enderecos e WHERE u.id =:id ORDER BY e.id DESC
```

Um usuário pode ter mais de dez endereços, então queremos trazer apenas dez endereços e caso o usuário queira, ele carrega de dez em dez.

Tentei usar [setMaxResults(int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Query.html#setMaxResults(int)) mas não obtive sucesso, pois como ele retorna apenas um usuário acredito que JPQL entenda que fez seu trabalho, mesmo que ao pegar a query espelhada no console e jogá-la no meu banco ele me retorne mais de uma linha.

É possívez fazer o que eu preciso? Caso positivo, como?

**EDIÇÃO: Mapeamento como pedido**

```
public class Usuario implements Serializable {  
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4769740907794027841L;

    // Outros atributos

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "usuario")
    private Set<Endereco> enderecos;

    // Sets e gets
}

public class Endereco implements Serializable { 
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6380840893466300379L;

    // Outros atributos

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "CD_USUARIO", nullable = false, referencedColumnName = "CD_USUARIO")
    private Usuario usuario;

    // Sets e gets
}
```

Além disso, eu tenho o comando [sql](/questions/tagged/sql) que me traz o que eu quero, mas eu quero, se possível, em JPQL para evitar uso de código não portável como o rownum do [oracle](/questions/tagged/oracle).

```
SELECT *
FROM user u INNER JOIN endereco e ON u.id_user = e.id_user
WHERE u.id_user = '123' AND ROWNUM = 1
ORDER BY e.id_address desc;
```

Comment: Ja tentou subquery ? dessa forma é possível utilizar limit dentro da subquery que irá buscar os endereços.

Comment: Philippe, poderia incluir o mapeamento do relacionamento entre `User` e `Address`?

Comment: @Wakim incluí o mapeamento e o SQL que eu tenho hoje que me traz o resultado que eu preciso.

Comment: Andei pesquisando um pouco e vi que a JPA não da suporte a paginação em mapeamentos. Você terá que ver a JPAQuery ou usar JPQL para buscar os endereços em prol de usar o mapeamento da entidade. Cheguei a achar essa pergunta do SO EN: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3970681/how-can-i-do-paging-with-onetomany-collections.

Comment: @Walkim foi mais ou menos a mesma resposta que recebi no SO em [How to limit entity list-property size with JPQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25491646/how-to-limit-entity-list-property-size-with-jpql)

Comment: Philippe, qual o seu provedor JPA? Hibernate? EclipseLink?

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly JPA puro.

Comment: Philippe, não existe JPA puro. JPA é uma especificação de serviços (pense como um conjunto e interfaces e classes abstratas), você ou seu servidor de aplicação tem que ter configurado um provedor JPA.

Comment: Assim, não usamos nada de framework algum com exceção do persistence que usa o Hibernate para as configurações.

Answer (score 4):

É realmente necessário fazer a consulta sob usuário?

Realizando a consulta em cima de endereço você conseguirá paginar com os métodos [setFirstResult(int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Query.html#setFirstResult(int)) e [setMaxResults(int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Query.html#setMaxResults(int))

Para paginar dentro do endereço que está dentro de usuário você precisará de auxílio, como descrito [na sugestão do Wakim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3970681/how-can-i-do-paging-with-onetomany-collections)

Aconselho trocar sua query para ser realizada a partir de `Endereço`, realizando `JOIN` com `Usuario` através do `ID` e paginar com os dois métodos citados

Comment: Eu preciso de todas as informações do usuário e os endereços. Você pode editar sua resposta e colocar um exemplo, por favor?

Comment: @PhilippeGioseffi Com a consulta não tem jeito. Não daria para fazer a paginação na view? Existem componentes que possuem essa facilidade.

Answer (score 1):

Fazendo o caminho inverso conforme sugestão do [Felipe Fonseca](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/6433/felipe-fonseca)

```
SELECT e
FROM Endereco e
WHERE e.usuario.id = :id
ORDER BY e.id DESC
```

Então você pode paginar normalmente

```
em.createQuery(query)
    .setParameter("id", id)
    .setMaxResults(10)
    .getResultList();
```

Se você quiser é inclusive possível retornar o usuario junto com o endereço (Resultado do tipo `Object[]`), porém, acho mais fácil buscar pelo usuário e pelos endereços em separado:

```
SELECT e, u
FROM Endereco e 
JOIN e.usuario u
WHERE u.id = :id
ORDER BY e.id DESC
```